# PHP fwrite without duplicate

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I want  to  write the code in such a way that,  it will write and save any input in a .TXT  file.  Then there should be functions that will search the whole file (txt)  if a text or word has been written or saved before,  it should bring error.

If someone has written Love and another person wants to input Love again, it should bring an error message.

here is my code

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$myfile=
fopen("man.txt" , "a+") or
die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, "Name:".$name. "\r\n")
?>
```

Comment: What code / approach have you tried so far?

Comment: Here is another code  <?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
if (empty($name))
{
echo "Please enter your name";
}
else $name=$name;
$myfile=
fopen("mam.txt" , "a+") or
die("Unable to open file!");
$path="mam.txt";
if (file_exists($path))
{
 $contents = file_get_contents($path);
 $contents = explode("\r\n", $contents);
 $users = array();
foreach ($contents as $value) {
 $user = explode("\r\n", $value);
 $users[$user[0]] = isset($user[1]) ? $user[1] :null;
}
 if (isset($users[$_POST['name']])) 
{
echo "Name exist";
}
else
echo "NO";
}
fwrite($myfile, $name. "\r\n")
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have used the `in_array` function to check an array we have populated (`$users`) for the submitted name.

If the name is found, is echos "Name Exists". If it is not found it echos "No" and adds the name.

```
<?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
if (empty($name)) { echo "Please enter your name"; } else $name=$name;

$myfile= fopen("mam.txt" , "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");

$path="mam.txt";

if (file_exists($path)) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($path);
    $contents = explode("\r\n", $contents);

    $users = array();

    foreach ($contents as $value) {
        $users[] = $value;
    }
    // Search the file for the submitted name
    if (in_array($name, $users)) {
        // The name already exists
        echo "Name exist";
    } else {
        // The name doesnt exist
        echo "NO"; 
        // Add the new name
        fwrite($myfile, $name. "\r\n");
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. If I refresh the page with nothing in the TeX field, it will tell me name exist. It's seeing empty space as array. Help